# Почему не получается сделать INSERT запрос к MySQL с записью переменных (С++)?

Tags: c++, mysql

Подскажите, почему при попытке использовать функцию выходит ошибка Error: can't execute INSERT-query? Что не так в запросе?

Структура таблицы

```
1   id  int(11)
2   time    datetime
3   rad int(11)
4   temp    float
5   hum float
6   pres    int(6)
```

Код

```
void insertToDb(short int r, float t, float h, short int p)
{
  MYSQL conn;
  if(!mysql_init(&conn))
    {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't create MySQL-descriptor\n");
     exit(1);
    }
  if(!mysql_real_connect(&conn,
                       "localhost",
                       "user",
                       "xxxxx",
                       "my_db",
                       0,
                       NULL,
                       0))
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", mysql_error(&conn));
   exit(1);
  }
   if(mysql_query(&conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'") != 0)
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't set character set\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  char query[400];
  sprintf(query,
          "INSERT INTO my_table(rad, temp, hum, pres) VALUES (%i, %f, %f, %i)",
          r, t, h, p);

  if(mysql_query(&conn,query) !=0);
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't execute INSERT-query\n");
    exit(1);
   }
  mysql_close(&conn);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, выведите сообщение об ошибке при помощи mysql_error() и дополните им ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!) Дело оказалось в отсутствии автоинкремента айди..

Answer (score 4):

Вы указали в тэгах и заголовке вопроса `C++`, но используете библиотеку написанную на `C`.
Рекомендую вам перейти первым делом на https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp или любой аналог, который вам по душе.

```
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO my_table(rad, temp, hum, pres) VALUES ('%i','%f','%f','%i')", r, t, h, p);
```

Для этого использовать `SqlStatement con->prepareStatement`.

И Binding Parameters а для контролирования ошибок использовать

```
try {
....code
} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << EXAMPLE_FUNCTION << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}
```

Больше примеров посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/tree/4ac7bbc847187fa957b30c1808c5b87023bb6feb/examples).

Удачной разработки!

Comment: Дело в том, что я понятия не имею это с или с++, простите уж за неграмотность.) Расширении файла было cpp, поэтому предположил. А вообще проблема оказалась в автоинкременте id. Спасибо за попытку помочь!

Comment: @user3843377  - проблема этого кода в том, что запрос собирается конкатенацией. Это открывает дорогу хакерам и SQL  - инъекциям.